# My question was closed as asking two questions but I'm only asking one

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question about [Cosmetic surgery and crime in Star Trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/267103/153074) which has been closed as not focused and a comment stating that it's asking two questions.

I'm slightly confused as I'm only asking one question which is mutually exclusive as far as I can tell.

The question is

> Are their any other known crimes undertaken by individuals who have had cosmetic surgery, or are there any in universe explanations on why this has not or could not happen?

The question is mutually exclusive. I can only see the following example answers being provided:

1. If an answer can provide multiple examples of crimes being committed by individuals then there cannot be reasons why it cannot happen (as it has happened).
2. If an answer can provide reasons why it cannot happen, then they cannot provide examples of crimes being committed (as crimes cannot happen).
3. An answer could provide examples of crimes being initiated but then being stopped by something. This then enters a Minority Report situation, as if a crime has been stopped before it has been committed is it still a crime, and would it then be a valid answer for the question.

I cannot see an answer being provided that states that multiple crimes have been committed and here is why the cannot happen as either the crimes happen or they cannot.

I can split the question into two separate questions but then I come across a chicken and egg situation about what question to ask first as they are interdependent on each other.

I could change the or in the middle of the original question to an and, which then technically makes it one question, but I feel that that is a very small semantic difference to close a question on.

Comment: Your third to last and second to last paragraphs are both asking different questions are they not?

Comment: I wasn't intentional trying to do that. It must have been an error in grammar as I was not trying to ask a question in my third to last paragraph. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

Your question, as [originally written](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/267103/revisions), asked two questions;

- Are there any instances of crimes being committed by people who've had plastic surgery?

  > Are their any other known crimes undertaken by individuals who have had cosmetic surgery, or are there any in universe explanations on why this has not or could not happen?
- Why isn't plastic surgery used more extensively?

  > With such a powerful procedure, is there any in universe explanation of why these procedures are not more widely undertaken than for the mission critical, save the Federation instances that seems to be it's normal use.

Questions that ask multiple things typically get closed as lacking focus. The latest edit (removing the latter question) has brought it back on-topic and it will likely be reopened shortly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, it was never my intention to ask what appeared to be a second question. I haven't even realised I had asked it, so that was why I was confused about the closure of the question

Comment: @A.Steer - They're both fair questions though